# 4 div elements side by side inside one main div element

Tags: css

I want to put 4 div elements, side by side eachother, into one main div element. I tried float:left, but  the div elements were not inside the main div element; Instead they were to the left of the browser page. Is there a way of using float:left for the main element instead of the entire browser page? Or using an entirely different method to display them side by side inside the main div element.

CSS code:

```
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {   
width: 125px;
height: 125px;
margin: 10px;
padding: 1px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.maindiv {
background-color: #e5e4d7;
margin:10px;
border-radius:5px;
padding:20px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="main1">
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event, 'div1')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div1')"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event, 'div2')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div2')"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event, 'div3')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div3')"></div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event, 'div4')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div4')"></div>
</div>
```

The drag/drop is for javascript which I am still trying to figure out, so ignore that part since I'm only doing css right now.
So far this works but the four div elements are stacked on eachother instead of side by side. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have the <div class="main1"> while in CSS you have class ".maindiv" make sure you have both names matching correctly

Comment: please mark it as an answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just give the container `div` `float: left;` as well

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8ukLgze/)

Answer (score 1):

put `overflow:hidden;` to the container when youre floating elements inside of it.

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {   
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
.main1{
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    margin:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="main1">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event, 'div1')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div1')"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event, 'div2')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div2')"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event, 'div3')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div3')"></div>
    <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event, 'div4')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div4')"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display: inline-block;` which helps center alignment.

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {   
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
.main1 {
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    margin:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main1">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event, 'div1')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div1')"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event, 'div2')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div2')"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event, 'div3')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div3')"></div>
    <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event, 'div4')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div4')"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use display:flex to achieve the same

```css
.main1{
      display:flex;
      border:1px solid black;
}
.main1 div{
      border:1px solid black;
      height:50px;
      width:50px;
      margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main1">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event, 'div1')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div1')"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event, 'div2')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div2')"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event, 'div3')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div3')"></div>
    <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event, 'div4')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div4')"></div>
</div>
```

If you want in each row only four div elements to be there you can use flex-wrap

```css
.main1{
     display:flex;
     flex-wrap:wrap;
     border:1px solid black;
}

.main1 div{
      flex-basis:20%;
      height:10vw;
      border:1px solid black;
      margin:10px;
      background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main1">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event, 'div1')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div1')"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event, 'div2')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div2')"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event, 'div3')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div3')"></div>
    <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event, 'div4')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div4')"></div>      
    <div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event, 'div5')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div5')"></div>
    <div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event, 'div6')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div6')"></div>
    <div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event, 'div7')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div7')"></div>
    <div id="div8" ondrop="drop(event, 'div8')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div8')"></div>
</div>
```